# Adding JSON property using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "staticInfo": {
        "browser": "Chrome",
        "browserVersion": "54.0",
        "packageNumber": "XXX",
        "user": "user"
    }
    ,
    "request": {
        "server": "E",
        "steps": {
            "Step1": {
                "start": "11/30/2016 20:11:26.494",
                "end": "11/30/2016 20:11:26.510"
            }
            ,
            "Step2": {
                "start": 1480536689237,
                "end": 1480536689357
            }
            ,
            "Step3": {
                "start": "Wed, 11/30/2016 20:12:25.229 GMT",
                "end": "Wed, 11/30/2016 20:12:25.246 GMT"
            }            
        }
        ,
        "url": "SomeURL",
        "trackingId": "99809eb5-c36b-4199-83d6-847c7b0489d1:0"
    }   
}
```

I am trying to add a Step4 so the final JSON looks like this

```
{
    "staticInfo": {
        "browser": "Chrome",
        "browserVersion": "54.0",
        "packageNumber": "XXX",
        "user": "user"
    }
    ,
    "request": {
        "server": "E",
        "steps": {
            "Step1": {
                "start": "11/30/2016 20:11:26.494",
                "end": "11/30/2016 20:11:26.510"
            }
            ,
            "Step2": {
                "start": 1480536689237,
                "end": 1480536689357
            }
            ,
            "Step3": {
                "start": "Wed, 11/30/2016 20:12:25.229 GMT",
                "end": "Wed, 11/30/2016 20:12:25.246 GMT"
            }
            ,
            "Step4": {
                "start": "SomeData",
                "end": "SomeData"
            }

        }
        ,
        "url": "SomeURL",
        "trackingId": "99809eb5-c36b-4199-83d6-847c7b0489d1:0"
    }    
}
```

So basically I am trying to add a `Step4`. I am trying to accomplish this using `Newtonsoft.Json`. I know that I can do it using basic string parsing but just for consistency I would like to use the `Newtonsoft.Json` class.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `JObject` also implements `IDictionary`, You can do:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
jObj["request"]["steps"]["Step4"] = JToken.FromObject(new { start = "some", end = "somedata" });
var newjson = jObj.ToString( Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

OR using `dynamic` keyword

```
dynamic jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
jObj.request.steps.Step4 = JToken.FromObject(new { start = "some", end = "somedata" });
var newjson = jObj.ToString( Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Nice observation, frankly I did not know about `IDictionary` implementation